# Java - Building GRect from the bottom left corner

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to create a Thermometer where I have an empty(white) stem and when getting a certain degrees Celsius, the stem fills up with mercury(red) by having two separate GRects(one white, the red one overlays the white). The trouble I'm having is that I can't make it seem like the mercury is filling up from the bottom. It either fills "down" starting at the top left corner going down like a normal GRect, or the red doesn't show up at all. I can't figure out how to invert the y coordinates so that it builds up instead of down..... Please help!! Thanks.

This is what I have for the positioning of the stems:

```
//Empty stem
GRect stemwhite = new GRect(200, 50, 50, 300);
stemwhite.setFilled(true);
stemwhite.setFillColor(Color.WHITE);
add(stemwhite);
//Fill stem
GRect stemred = new GRect(200, 50, 50, 300 * (tempC / 100);
stemred.setFilled(true);
stemred.setFillColor(Color.RED);
add(stemred);
```

tempC is the degrees Celsius that the user inputs. The only problem with this is the red is at the top of the white stem. I've tried a couple different things, like " -(300 * (tempC / 100); ", but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: We need to see your code to see what the issue is.

Comment: Just put in some code. Sorry, new to stackoverflow. :P